# Error: Socket Timeout While Installing Truffle Using npm - Good Internet Connection, Need Assistance

Tags: npm, blockchain, npm-install, truffle

- I'm running the command: npm install -g truffle on windows 10 cmd.
- I've verified my network connection by accessing other websites without any problems.
- I've attempted the installation on multiple occasions, and the error consistently occurs.
- The specific error message I'm getting is: "Socket timeout."

```
>npm install -g truffle
npm WARN deprecated testrpc@0.0.1: testrpc has been renamed to ganache-cli, please use this package from now on.
npm WARN deprecated @ensdomains/resolver@0.2.4: Please use @ensdomains/ens-contracts
npm WARN deprecated @ensdomains/ens@0.4.5: Please use @ensdomains/ens-contracts
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.6.1: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Demo1\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-08T08_16_21_785Z-debug-0.log
```

I expect that the installation of Truffle using npm should complete successfully without encountering a "Socket Timeout" error. I'm new to Truffle and npm, so I'm not sure what might be causing this issue. I'm seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I managed to resolve the "Socket timeout" error when trying to install the truffle package. Here's how I did it:

Create a .npmrc configuration file in the directory where you're running the installation command.

Open the .npmrc file in a text editor.

Add the following line to increase the timeout for network requests:

```
timeout=60000
```

**This sets the timeout to 60,000 milliseconds (60 seconds). The default timeout for network requests in npm is 3,000 milliseconds (3 seconds).**

Save the .npmrc file.

To verify the current timeout setting, you can run the following command in your terminal:

```
npm config get timeout
```

Run the installation command again:

```
npm install -g truffle
```

This solution worked for me and allowed the installation to complete without the "Socket timeout" error. Increasing the timeout gave npm more time to establish connections and download packages, which resolved the connectivity issue.